# Is there a numericupdown event for value increasing in c#

Tags: c#, events, numericupdown, eventhandler

I need an event that happens when the up arrow is pressed and another when the down arrow is pressed. is there an event handler for this? all I can find is valuechanged?

Comment: Asking a question like this in general doesnt make any sense...

Comment: Can you store the previous value and when the value changes work out if it was an increase?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Decimal OldValue;
private void NumericUpDown1_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) {

   if (NumericUpDown1.Value>OldValue)
      {
         ///value increased, handle accordingly
      }
    else if (NumericUpDown1.Value<OldValue)
      {
        ///value decreased, handle accordingly
      }
    else
      {
        return;
      }
 OldValue=NumericUpDown1.Value;
}
```

Comment: This puts it in a loop

Answer (score 3):

The short answer is **no**, there is no such event.
However it would be easy to check if it is an increase or decrease in value. For example if you bind the `numericupdown`'s value to a property in your view model, you could do it like this:

```
private int upDownValue;

public int UpDownValue
{
    get{ return this.upDownValue; }
    set
    {
        if(value > this.upDownValue)
        {
             //It increased
        }

        if(value < this.upDownValue)
        {
            //It decreased
        }

        this.upDownValue = value;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi im new to programming, i dont really understand whats going on here, what do you mean by view model?

Comment: @john there is no short answer to what view model means. It's part of a design pattern called [Model-View-ViewModel](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419663.aspx) that is often used when making UI applications. Check the link and learn about it if you are interested.

Comment: I edited a post below that seems to work for me, thanks anyway I will look into that

Answer (score 0):

If you use the NumericUpDown from Mahapps framework you can use the ValueIncremented and ValueDecremented events.